# Form validation using AngularJS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am planning to do a simple form validation using AngularJS but it seems not to be working. Here is my plunkr file: http://plnkr.co/edit/sEPAhszlFofLfb87uh8S.

I don't know why, everything seems good but it is not firing.

My html file:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        body     { padding-top:30px; }
    </style>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>AngularJS Form Validation</h1>
      </div>
      <!-- =================================================================== -->
      <!-- FORM ============================================================== -->
      <!-- =================================================================== -->
      <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
      <form name="regForm" ng-submit="submitForm(regForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : regForm.name.$invalid && (regForm.name.$dirty || submitted)}">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Full Name" ng-required="true">
                  <br/>
                  <p ng-show="regForm.name.$error.required && (regForm.name.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Please provide your full name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : regForm.email.$invalid && (regForm.email.$dirty || submitted)}">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email Address" ng-required="true">
                <p ng-show="regForm.email.$error.required && (regForm.email.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Email is required.</p>
                <p ng-show="regForm.email.$error.email && (regForm.email.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : regForm.contactno.$invalid && (regForm.contactno.$dirty || submitted) }">
                <input type="text" name="contactno" class="form-control" ng-model="user.contactno" placeholder="Phone number" ng-pattern="^0[0-9]{2}[- ]?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4,5}$" maxlength="11"  ng-required="true">
                <p ng-show="regForm.contactno.$error.required && regForm.contactno.$error.pattern && (regForm.contactno.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Enter a valid phone number.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : regForm.org.$invalid && (regForm.org.$dirty || submitted)}">
                <input type="text" name="org" class="form-control" ng-model="user.org" placeholder="Organization Name" ng-required="true">
                <p ng-show="regForm.org.$error.required && (regForm.org.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Please input name of your organization</p>
            </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

My js file:

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) { 
            alert('our form is amazing');
        }

    };

});
```

I just need it to validate that all required fields have the related input and not empty fields.

Comment: You are getting console error `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '0' is an unexpected token at column 2 of the expression [^0[0-9]{2}[- ]?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4,5}$] starting at [0[0-9]{2}[- ]?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4,5}$].`

Comment: It's works here http://jsbin.com/bukizagaja/1/ when you enter a valide inforamtion on form you will the alter poped up

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-pattern` should be `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{2}[- ]?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4,5}$/"` instead of `ng-pattern="^0[0-9]{2}[- ]?[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4,5}$"` regx pattern should use escaping character `/` at the start & end of the expression.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VyGjDKLkDDkP5KvnkRQu?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is wrong, from the angular documentation:

> ngPattern (optional) string
>   Sets pattern validation error key if the
>   value does not match the RegExp pattern expression. Expected value is
>   /regexp/ for inline patterns or regexp for patterns defined as scope
>   expressions.

So putting a forward slash at the start and end of your pattern should work